# Why is China's relationship with Canada still strained when China has improved its ties with both Australia and the United States in recent times?

Tags: china, canada

> On Sunday, Global Times, published by the Chinese Communist Party’s
> central committee, heralded the visit as an opportunity “to ease the
> strained China-Canada relations.” However, it quoted a source warning
> that if Guilbeault “demands” that China become more aggressive on
> carbon emissions “in a condescending tone” the result could be
> “counterproductive.”
>
> “Even before the meeting starts, they’re giving us our marching
> orders,” said Margaret McCuaig-Johnston, a board member with the China
> Strategic Risks Institute. “Don’t push the envelope. Don’t push China
> to do more. And frankly, the minister (Guilbeault) himself said he was
> going to have an open and frank conversation. Good for him.”
>
> At the time that Prime Minister Justin Trudeau was first elected in
> 2015, there was considerable enthusiasm in official Ottawa for the
> idea of broadening relations and trade with China, to the extent that
> the Liberal government was working on a free-trade deal and an
> extradition treaty with Beijing.
>
> But, relations have since deteriorated.

https://calgaryherald.com/news/guilbeault-warned-against-condescending-to-china

Why is China's relationship with Canada still strained when China has improved its ties with both Australia and the United States in recent times? China did away with its trade measures against Australia and has announced it will cooperate with the United States on fentanyl and other issues and reestablish military communication with the U.S., but it has yet to make such a move toward Canada. Is there a reason given for this? The Chinese spokesperson is usually pretty straightforward and even the Global Times sometimes spell out what they expect from other countries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Question:**
>
> Why is China's relationship with Canada still strained when China has improved its ties with both Australia and the United States in recent times?

**Short Answer**

I think China would like to say relations with Australia and the U.S. are improving and Canada is left out in the cold.  It's their divide and conquer strategy.   I think reality is all three close allies are still weary of China's actions and none of them would say relations are improving.

**Answer**

**[Xi Jinping tells Anthony Albanese China-Australia ties are now ‘on the right path’](https://www.scmp.com/news/china/diplomacy/article/3240552/xi-jinping-tells-anthony-albanese-china-australia-ties-are-now-right-path)**

I don't think your source  Global Times facts are accurate, nor up to date.

Ties between Australia and China are not improving.  Yes China says it's willing to drop it's trade sanctions against Australian goods.  Nov 4-7 Australia's Prime Minister Anthony Albanese had a state visit in China, first time in 7 years they've had such high level talks.  Problem is on Nov 14th an Australian destroyer put into Japan's exclusive economic zone to clear fishing nets from their propellers.   A Chinese destroyer approached.  The Australian ship warned the Chinese ship to stay clear, they had divers in the water.  The Chinese ship ignores them and hit's the ship with a sonar ping loud enough to injure the Australian divers in the water.  The Australian PM did not feel comfortable bringing this event up with a Chinese delegation in Canberra.  The Australian public is upset with their PM's "sensitivity" to China's feelings.

- **[PM defends handling of Chinese warship saga in Question Time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAkNHH4pW7s)**
- **[Albanese ‘failed’ to stand up for Australians in Chinese warship incident](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWQBXkoEI-M)**

And Beijing is now Pushing it.

- **[Chinese official warns Australia on navy movements in East, South China Seas](https://www.reuters.com/world/asia-pacific/chinese-official-warns-australia-navy-movements-east-south-china-seas-2023-11-28/)**

US China relations are not improving either.  They are more **[about crisis prevention](https://www.cnbc.com/2023/11/14/us-china-relations-are-now-more-about-crisis-prevention.html)** than anything else.  That's better than nothing, but it's a long way from good.

All three strong allies remain very concerned and wary of China's actions and continue to distance themselves from China economically and politically.